# Workaround for numpy broadcasting rule

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am currently analyzing some data from a study. This study has 27 participants, each participant data is represented as a 3-dimensional numpy array. For example, the data for participant one has the shape (22, 59, 751). I wanted to combine all those 27 arrays into a 4-dimensional array that has the shape (22, 59, 751, 27). What I did was to initialize a new 4D array filled with 0.

```
comb_data = np.zeros((22, 59, 751, 27))
```

Then I looped through each array and then assigned it to the corresponding location.

```
for i, participant in enumerate(control_files):
    comb_data[:, :, :, i] = np.load(os.path.join(path_control, participant))[:, :, :]
```

However, some array has a different shape size (due to issues in data collection). Therefore, I am now facing this situation:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (15,59,751) into shape (22,59,751)
```

I want the array to be assigned wherever possible, and then fill/keep the remaining as 0s. What are possible ways to workaround this situation ?. Is there anyway to make the 'smaller' array auto-fill 0 values into the 'bigger' one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the space filled with zeros, you simply need to restrict to the size of the array that you are given.

```
for i, participant in enumerate(control_files):
    a,b,c = participant.shape
    comb_data[:a, :b, :c, i] = np.load(os.path.join(path_control, participant))[:, :, :]
```

Unfortunately, numpy is not going to take tensor of shape X and arbitrarily cast it into a tensor of shape Y, automatically filling in zeros. This is mostly because there are thousands of ways to fill in the zeros, it doesn't have to be systematic.

Comment: Thanks, so it's just a simple case of indexing.

Comment: Ya, added a little more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, first you need to know your biggest shape, then you initialize you zeros matrix and copy its dimensions according to the shape of each element.

```py
data_list = [np.load(os.path.join(path_control, p)) for p in control_files]
largest_shape = np.max(np.array([m.shape for m in data_list]), axis=0)
comb_data = np.zeros([len(data_list)]+largest_shape.tolist())
for i, m in enumerate(data_list):
    comb_data[i, :m.shape[0], :m.shape[1], :m.shape[2]] = m
```

In this example I have put the index for each person first, but you can also put it last.